# Login from Universal App to Web Api using Live Id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, windows-phone-8.1, liveid

I'm trying to implement following functionality:

1. User signs in into Live Id account from Windows Phone 8.1 (or Universal) app.
2. App accesses Web Api that I develop with ASP.NET Web Api 2
3. In this Web Api I need to authenticate the user.
4. Later, I want to authenticate same user in web app

Here is what I'm doing, and it doesn't work.

In my Windows Phone App:

```
var authClient = new LiveAuthClient("http://myservice.cloudapp.net");
LiveLoginResult result = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin" });

if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
{
    connected = true;
    var identity = await ConnectToApi(result.Session.AuthenticationToken);
    Debug.WriteLine(identity);
}
```

And then

```
private async Task<string> ConnectToApi(string token)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myservice.cloudapp.net/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        // HTTP GET
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/values");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return result;
        }
        else
            return response.ReasonPhrase;
    }
}
```

And then in my web api I have following

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{

    app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        clientId: "my client id",
        clientSecret: "my secret");

}
```

I registered http://myservice.cloudapp.net as redirect url.

The problem is authentication doesn't work, web api actions do not recognize the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it totally wrong. First, I actually need to use app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication method. The example was found here http://code.lawrab.com/2014/01/securing-webapi-with-live-id.html. But when I tried, I got this error in the output

`IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 1,
    Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )`

This one took me a while to figure out, until I found this post: [JwtSecurityTokenHandler 4.0.0 Breaking Changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593435/jwtsecuritytokenhandler-4-0-0-breaking-changes)

Putting these things together, I got the solution that seems to work now in my testing environment:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
        var sKey = "<Secret key>" + "JWTSig";
        var secretBytes = new UTF8Encoding(true, true).GetBytes(sKey);
        var signingKey = sha256.ComputeHash(secretBytes);
        var securityKeyProvider = new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider("urn:windows:liveid", signingKey);
        var securityKey = securityKeyProvider.SecurityTokens.First().SecurityKeys.First();

        var jwtOptions = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            //AllowedAudiences = new[] { "<url>" },
            //IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new[] 
            //{ 
            //  new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider("urn:windows:liveid",signingKey)
            //},
            TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, keyIdentifier, validationParameters) =>
                    {
                        return securityKey;
                    },
                ValidAudience = "<url>",
                ValidIssuer = securityKeyProvider.Issuer
            }

        };
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtOptions);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking to do this from JavaScript I managed to get this working by following steps from this blog. You can find the audience by putting your token through jwt.io

https://blog.dirk-eisenberg.de/2014/08/30/validate-authentication_token-from-microsoft-liveid-with-node-express-jwt/

```
const validateLiveJWT = (token) => {
    const secret = '<<SECRET>>';
    const sha256 = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    sha256.update(secret + 'JWTSig', 'utf8');
    const secretBase64 = sha256.digest('base64');
    const secret = new Buffer(secretBase64, 'base64');

    const options = {
        audience: '<<AUDIENCE>>',
        issuer: 'urn:windows:liveid',
    };

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        jwt.verify(token, secret, options, (err: any, claims: any) => {
            if (err) {
                resolve(undefined);
            } else {
                resolve(claims);
            }
        });
    });
}
```